# Setting bar spacing in a matplotlib bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a matplotlib.bar plot and I can't figure out how to space the bars further apart so the labels are readable.

Here is my code

```
import matplotlib  
matplotlib.use('Agg')  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
def makePlot(self, data, labels, title, fileName):  
    plt.bar(range(1,len(data)+1), data, align="center")  
    plt.title(title)  
    plt.xticks(range(1, len(labels)+1), labels)  
    plt.savefig(fileName)  
    plt.clf()
```

Comment: Why not swapping the x- and y-axis (to facilitate reading of the x-labels)? Moreover, if the X's have no particular order, you can reorder them by increasing or decreasing values of Y.

Comment: The categories on the x-axis represent sort of a trend over time, so it makes more sense for them to stay on the x-axis. I'm mostly bothered by the large amount of space on the right side of the plot- why can't I just increase the spacing of the bars to fill in that space, or why isn't that happening automatically?

Comment: You can use the `plt.xlim()` function to manually set the limits of the x axis.

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you. Would you mind editing that into your answer so it's more clear that it answered my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the size of the figure by calling `plt.figure(figsize=(x,y))` where `x` and `y` are the width and height in inches.  That line must be before you call `plt.bar`.

Alternatively, you can make the label font smaller.  You would do that by changing your call to `xticks` to `plt.xticks(range(1, len(labels)+1), labels, size='small')`.

One more thing to try is to use the plt.xlim() function to manually set the limits of the x axis.

Comment: This helps, but is it possible to set the spacing of the bars manually?